# How to get Spring Integration Http.inboundGateway to return HAL Json?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-hateoas, spring-integration-http

I set the following property to true "spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type' & added org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas as a dependency.

**Code**

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myUserFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/user")
                    .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(HttpMethod.GET))
                    .get()
            )
            .handle((payload, headers) -> new MyUser("Joe Blogs")
                    .add(Link.of("http://localhost:8080/account", LinkRelation.of("account"))))
            .get();
}
```

**Response**

```
GET http://localhost:8080/user
HTTP/1.1 200 
connection: Keep-Alive, keep-alive
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 11 Jan 2021 18:31:13 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60

{
  "name": "Joe Blogs",
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "account",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/account"
    }
  ]
}

Response code: 200; Time: 19ms; Content length: 87 bytes
```

I expected the reponse to be returned in a HAL format e.g.

```
{
  "name": "Joe Blogs",
  "_links": [
    {
      "account":{
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/account"
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

Why is this not the case? And how can I make it so?

Sample application: https://github.com/kevvvvyp/si-hateoas-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is like this:

```
public IntegrationFlow myUserFlow(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/user")
                    .messageConverters(requestMappingHandlerAdapter.getMessageConverters().toArray(HttpMessageConverter[]::new))
```

The problem is because Spring Integration HTTP channel adapters are not auto-configured by Spring Boot and they are definitely not aware of your HAL customization.

So, we need to wait until the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` is processed by Spring Boot and hateoas customization. Then we take its converters and inject them into our `Http.inboundGateway()`.

I wanted to say that we may think about something automatic in Spring Boot to pick that customization up, but since we really don't talk about some infrastructure like MVC's `@RequestMapping` but rather some concrete beans, it is really probably better to stick with an explicit configuration.

I'm not sure though why can't we use `HttpMessageConverters` instead, but looks like `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` is configured later on, when this kind of beans (`IntegrtionFlow`) have already parsed and created.